# AMCL losting problem

Tags: ros, navigation, pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello... I work on AMCL. if I work in little area AMCL work very well. But if I work in corridor AMCL always is losting in the middle of corridor. My AMCL parameters are good so amcl pose estimation (pose arrays) doesnt spread. why it get lost always same area ??? problem is about **LIDAR MAX RANGE** or gound type ?

lidar hokuyo : 5.4 m max range
type of floor : tile
The length of the corridor :

[image: image description]

[**VIDEO ABOUT PROBLEM :**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFss-e_lgmQ&feature=youtu.be)

VIDEO INFO :

**video timing (03:08) : robot is actually in front of the first door, but amcl estimation is still in front of the first floor
video timing (04:07) : robot is actually in front of the third door, but amcl estimation is still in front of the second floor**

```
    <!-- amcl.XML-->
<launch>
  <arg name="use_map_topic"   default="true"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x"  default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y"  default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a"  default="0.0"/>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" args="scan:=scan2" output="screen">
<!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->

<param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom_combined"/>
<param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>
<param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
<param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>

<param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.5" />
<param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/> <!-- 5 -->
<param name="laser_max_beams" value="80"/>  <!-- 30 -->
<param name="min_particles" value="100"/>
<param name="max_particles" value="4000"/>
<param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
<param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
<param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.02"/> <!-- 0.2 -->
<param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.07"/> <!-- 0.2 -->
<!-- translation std dev, m -->
<param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.08"/> <!-- 0.8 -->
<param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.02"/> <!-- 0.2 -->
<param name="laser_max_range" value="5.6"/>
<param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.95"/>
<param name="laser_z_short" value="0.1"/>
<param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
<param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.05"/>
<param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
<param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
<param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
<param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
<!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
<param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
<param name="update_min_d" value="0.08"/>  <!-- 0.2 **0.15-->
<param name="update_min_a" value="0.18"/>  <!-- 0.5 **0.12-->

<param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
<param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/> <!-- 0.1 -->
<param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
<param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>

<param name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
<param name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
<param name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
<param name="use_map_topic" value="$(arg use_map_topic)"/>

</node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217059/amcl-losting-problem/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2015-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-04**:
This cannot be debugged without more information.

Please provide at least your configuration (min. `amcl`), maybe a video (from `rviz`) how this happens, or a bagfile.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-04**:
thanks... I edited my question @mig

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-07**:
can you help me @mig please ?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-09-07**:
It's rather difficult to tell what's happening, though I would be concerned that the particles are staying so bundled. Particles are supposed to spread out. This means that the algorithm is resampling, so check your odometry/laser rangefinders/map scale? One of those is likely the problem.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-07**:
thank you @allenh1. I placed boxes center of the corridor. and I mapped again. and now AMCL doesnt loss . so work well. ı cant understand ? And I learned that" if particles doesnt spread out , AMCL work so good ", doesnt it ????  I changed always amcl parameters and fixed that spread out particles.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-10**:
I'm really not sure what is happening there. To me, it seems, that you don't have proper odometry measurements. Could you create a bagfile and upload this somewhere?

Particles *need* to spread out to some extent. To me, it seems you are overestimating the (faulty) odometry. but this is just a guess

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-10**:
. I placed boxes center of the corridor. and I mapped again. and now AMCL doesnt loss. corridor length is longer then my lidar max range. is it a problem you think ? and if particles dont spread out  , Does that amcl parameters are very good . ı know so ??? you think my parameters are bad @mig ??

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-09-12**:
I'd say that you're odometry parameters are too low. On our [robots](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_navigation/blob/indigo_dev/cob_navigation_global/launch/amcl_node.xml), they are considerably higher and work fine.

But as I don't know your robot, I cannot say.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2015-09-12**:
my robot speed 0.2 m/sn. but when i increased my odom parameters , my amcl pose estimations spread out a lot .
you think is it a really problem ? ı think problem about lidar max range , lidat can not see end of the corridor.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-09-19**:
I'd say that this could be a good sign.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-09-19**:
Idea: map without odometry (e.g. hector slam) and then try to get your robot to localize.

**Comment by [nadiah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41411/nadiah/) on 2020-01-06**:
Hallo, did you solve this problem? because now I have the same problem like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping is locating robot via laser. Even if odometry is poor, gmapping is correcting position of robot with scan matching. But in corridor, your laser's range isn't enough for this.

Test your odometry first:

...

The first test checks how reasonable the odometry is for rotation. I open up rviz, set the frame to "odom," display the laser scan the robot provides, set the decay time on that topic high (something like 20 seconds), and perform an in-place rotation. Then, I look at how closely the scans match each other on subsequent rotations. Ideally, the scans will fall right on top of each other, but some rotational drift is expected, so I just make sure that the scans aren't off by more than a degree or two.

...

For more, look at [this navigation tuning guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide).

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-02-10**:
I control my robot with a joystick so path is no problem. If I do odometry tests in a room (5x5 m) , odometry result is very good and no problem. But when I drive my robot in corridor ( about pic. above), amcl get lost position of robot.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-10**:
I'm editing my answer because my comment is long,

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-02-10**:
is there a way or parameter to compensate this drifting ? (except a new lidar )

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-10**:
No, If This problem about your odometry settings, You must correct them first. Try editing your urdf file by looking other open source robot's urdfs.

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-02-11**:
I use a real robot and urdf model is same with robot. And I use laser_scan_matcher to produce odometry.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-11**:
I used real informations about my robot before too. But sometimes navigation needs some tricks like [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/226058/odometry-isnt-reasonable-for-rotational-motion/).